# How can a random variable which can't exist have a finite probability?

Tags: probability-theory

We have an event defined as the Measurement of Temperature, random variable being temperature itself.

Suppose Temperature is a Gaussian random variable with mean $T_0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then according to the bell distribution, we have some finite value of probability assigned to negative temperatures as well. So, should we constraint the *Density function* from lower side, but then it wouldn't be a Gaussian distribution, or should we accept the non physical values we obtain as it is? Or is it I am completely wrong in my understanding?

Comment: It's a simplification for mathematical convenience. Inserting some fairly realistic numbers you might describe a temperature as being normally distributed with mean 300 K and standard deviation 10 K. Then negative temperatures are 30 sigma events which basically don't happen anyway. In reality this is a flaw in the model, but it's not really an issue in practice.

Comment: That's it right.. There's nothing profound about it. I just wanted to clarify and now i have. Thanks.

Comment: The value of the Gaussian bell curve at any point is not the probability that the temperature measured will equal that value. For a continuous random variable, the probability that the random variable takes any specific value equals zero.

Comment: @AGuyWhoWantsToSucceed Yes, you're technically correct, but isn't it clear from context what OP means? They are simply asking about the fact that $P(T_0 < 0) > 0$....

Comment: Oh yes. I am sorry I didn't comprehend the question correctly.